# PyCharm says No Module named Crypto

Tags: python, pycharm, pycrypto, pycryptodome

I keep getting an import error saying:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Crypto'
```

I have gone over various other answers about how to resolve this, but it does not mention how I can resolve the issue in PyCharm.

I originally tried to `pip3 install pycrpyto`  in the Pycharm terminal, but it would not install. Then I hear about pycryptodome and was able to install it properly. However, when I type `import Crypto` , it keeps saying that the module was not found. How is this issue resolved in Pycharm.

Comment: You likely installed the package for a different Python installation than the one which PyCharm is set to use. Are you using virtual environments?

Comment: I am using virtual environments. But I installed it in the PyCharm terminal where it said (venv) <project path> so I thought it would be installed for the project. How can I install it for the virtual env

Comment: Can you try installing it through the Project Interpreter settings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Go to settings-->project:project_name-->Project Interpreter
- now you can see plus(+) symbol beside project,version,latest version (table),
  click on that
- a new tab will appear, type the package you want to install and click on install package which is at the left bottom of that tab

Note: check if it is capital c or small c, the packages are case sensitive

Answer (score 1):

Go to:
Pycharm>File>Settings>Python Interpreter> click +

Search for the package: Crypto or cryptography

and click install.

If the install fails with the SSL error:
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/crypto-mediator/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/crypto-mediator/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1076)'))) - skipping

Go back to the same page and after selecting the package click on the checkbox Options and mention: --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org
and then install the package